# Unexpected result with weights in spatstat::density.psp()

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

I am trying to use kernel density smoothing to map the intensity of possible pest escape from vehicle traffic. Each route has been broken down into straight lines with each line having an integer attribute for the number of times the segment was travelled upon. However, when I use this attribute as the weight in kernel density smoothing, the weights don't seem to be used.

I've created a simplified reprex below with two abutting straight lines. Can anyone explain to me how I can make density.psp() account for the fact that one segment has an attribute 2x the magnitude of the other?

Many thanks for your help,

Josh

```
    # Load packages 
    library(spatstat)
    
    # Create the data frame. Note that coordinates are projected to the
    # North America Lambert Conformal Conic system. https://epsg.io/102009
    my_lines <- data.frame(
      fx = c(1252365.22479882, 1233600.0015391),
      fy = c(510853.438463705, 626675.859171899),
      tx = c(1233600.0015391, 1218256.03484937),
      ty = c(626675.859171899, 721347.256108354),
      attrib = c(100, 50)
    ) 
    
    # Creat the observation window
    my_owin <- owin(
      xrange = c(1200000, 1270000),
      yrange = c(500000,  730000)
    ) 
    
    # Create the psp object with 'attrib' as the mark. 
    my_psp <- psp(
      x0 = my_lines$fx, y0 = my_lines$fy,
      x1 = my_lines$tx, y1 = my_lines$ty,
      window = my_owin, marks = my_lines$attrib
    )
    
    # Create the KDS image with 'attrib' as the weights
    kdi_image_weighted <-
      density.psp(
        my_psp,
        kernel = "gaussian",
        sigma = 4000,
        weights = my_psp$attrib,
        edge = FALSE
      )
    
    # Create the KDS image without weights
    kdi_image_unweighted <-
      density.psp(
        my_psp,
        kernel = "gaussian",
        sigma = 4000,
        edge = FALSE
      )
    
    # Plot the weighted and unweighted KDS images. Note that they are the same 
    # despite one being weighted. 
    plot(kdi_image_weighted) 
    plot(kdi_image_unweighted)
```

[image: comparison of weighted and unweighted KDI images. Note that they are seemingly identical]

Comment: Hi Josh Persi, it seems that `weights = my_psp$num_trips` in the `kdi_image_weighted <- density.psp(...)` code does not refer to anything. Maybe, try with `weights = my_psp$marks`. Cheers

Comment: Hi @lovalery, thanks for catching that! My code was supposed to read `weights = my_psp$attrib` after I renamed the `num_trips` column to make this reprex more general. However, switching `weights = my_psp$marks` works and provides the expected output! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Use `marks()` to extract the mark values from an object in the `spatstat` package. Example:

```
 Z <- density(my_psp, weights=marks(my_psp))
```

**Long answer:**

This problem is not related to the function `density.psp`.

Firstly there is a misunderstanding about names of objects. In your example, an object `my_psp` is created as `psp(.... marks=my_lines$attrib)`. Then the subsequent code expects `my_psp` to contain an element `my_psp$attrib`. This is not how evaluation works in R.

When you type the command `psp(...., marks=my_lines$attrib)`, the expression `my_lines$attrib` will be evaluated (by extracting the element called `attrib` from the object `my_lines`). After evaluating these data, the system forgets where it got the data from; the name `attrib` is forgotten. The resulting data (that was stored in `my_lines$attrib`) will be passed to the function `psp` as the argument `marks`.

Secondly you are using the `$` operator to extract data from an object (in this case an object of class `"psp"` in the `spatstat` package). This is OK for simple objects such as lists, but for objects created by packages it is unsafe, because the internal structure could change when the package is updated.

Your example code expects the object `my_psp` to contain an element with a particular name, but there's no reason why it should. The function `psp()` creates an object of class `"psp"` which has some weird internal structure, described in `help(psp.object)`.

To extract the mark values from an object in the `spatstat` package, it is currently possible to use `$marks`, but this could change, and it is strongly recommended to use the function `marks()`.